# creating htaccess undisplay my folder.. How to solve this?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in my htaccess file i have the following contents..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
```

when i am enabling this htaccess file my project directory is not showing in localhost :(

http://localhost/MyStartUp/OurProDeal/admin/ - showing internal server error and http://localhost/MyStartUp/OurProDeal/ not showing admin directory.

this htaccess file is working fine in my other machine.... any help

---

Error i am getting

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: What does the error.log say for the internal error? Why disable -Indexes if you want to view the directory contents(?)?

Comment: htaccess file is hidden by default. you need to enable display hidden files.

Comment: Hi @mario in php error log file i am not seeing anything.. i have added the error which i am getting while access

Comment: @SavanKoradia i am not talking about htaccess file. my admin dir is not showing it..

Comment: `AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all`

maybe this will work

Comment: Excerpt the last five lines of your vhost or `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. There is **always** an entry for 500 / internal errors.